# Idiotic determinant mistake?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I need to calculate $$\begin{vmatrix} \lambda & -1 & 0 & 0\\ -1 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda & -1 \\  0 & 0 & -1 & \lambda \end{vmatrix}.$$

For the life of me I don't see what my mistake is: expanding in the first row we have
$$\lambda^2(\lambda ^2-1)-(-1)(-1)(\lambda ^2-1)= (\lambda^2-1)^2 .$$ What is my error?

Comment: Why do you believe it is incorrect?

Comment: This is correct!

Comment: Why do you think you've made mistake? Because this is the correct determinant.

Comment: @Fabian because of [this](https://matrixcalc.org/en/#diagonalize%28%7B%7B0,1,0,0%7D,%7B1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,1,0%7D%7D%29).

Comment: The determinant of a diagonal block matrix is given by $$\det\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{pmatrix} = \det A \det B.$$ With that you easily see that your result is correct.

Comment: But $(\lambda^2-1)^2 = (\lambda - 1)(\lambda - 1)(\lambda + 1)(\lambda + 1)$, so you have the same answer as that link.

Comment: Welcome, @linalg, to the glorious world of being an idiot about basic math. It is a fabulous world, and as mayor of the world, I welcome you. :)

Answer (score 15):

As everyone comments, my answer is correct.

Comment: But if you hadn't asked, you would still be puzzled. Nothing wrong with any question, however shameful you may think it is.

Comment: Maybe a little humor will help. One of my favorites: "There are no stupid questions, just stupid people." Hee hee.

Comment: Upvote for being puzzled and solving it, best way to learn :)

Comment: So many UPVOTES for a realisation that the so-called mistake never existed, instead of deleting or closing the question. From when did people on this site become so liberal about upvotes?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate as to how you got the answer, so this question will be more helpful to future visitors.